# Setting up nginx with multiple IPs

Tags: linux, nginx

I have my nginx configuration file under /etc/nginx/sites-available/ with two upstreams say

```
upstream test1 {
server 1.1.1.1:50;
server 1.1.1.2:50;
}

upstream test2 {
server 2.2.2.1:60;
server 2.2.2.2:60;
}

server {
location / {
proxy_pass http://test1;
}
location / {
proxy_pass http://test2;
}
}
```

Sending a curl request to `<PrimaryIP>:80` works but I want to use `<SecondaryIP1>:80` for `test1` and `<SecondaryIP2>:80` for `test2`. Is it possible to define this in nginx?

Comment: You want virtual hosts so use 2 server sections https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/. See also https://serverfault.com/questions/241029/virtual-host-from-ip-address

Comment: Only one block will be reachable in your case. You need to use virtual host as @ivo mentioned

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to have two server directives to accomplish this task:

```
upstream test1 {
     server 1.1.1.1:50;
     server 1.1.1.2:50;
}

upstream test2 {
     server 2.2.2.1:60;
     server 2.2.2.2:60;
 }

 server {
      listen 80
      server_name <SecondartIP1>
      location / {
          proxy_pass http://test1;
       }
 }
server {
     listen 80
     server_name <SecondarIP2>
     location / {
          proxy_pass http://test2;
      }
 }
```