# Nginx different IPs, same port - bind() fail

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to serve 2 different frontends on same 443 port but with different IP's. However `nginx -t` fails with `nginx: [emerg] bind() to 10.10.1.1:443 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)`. Here's my conf's:

Conf 1:

```
server {
    listen 10.10.0.1:443 ssl http2;
}
```

Conf 2:

```
server {
    listen 10.10.1.1:443 ssl http2;
}
```

I have no `443` port open by any other process - `netstat -tulpn | grep :443` gives nothing. I assume that second bind fails after binding first block. For example, if I change second block to `listen 133.10.1.1:443` I get no errors.

There is no `default` configs in my `sites-enabled` folder.

Please help sort it out =)

Upd:

```
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.1.1 serv serv
127.0.0.1 localhost

#Custom
10.10.0.1 main.site
10.10.1.1 test.site
```

Upd:

```
# ip addr sh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet *<external IP>*/20 brd *<external IP>* scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.24.0.5/16 brd 10.24.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.150.0.2/16 brd 10.150.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: int0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.10.0.1/16 scope global int0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`10.10.0.0` - tunnel network, server conf 1 works perfectly on `10.10.0.1` without conf 2 enabled.
Upd:

```
# route -n                              
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         <external IP>   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 int0
10.24.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
10.150.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
<external IP>   0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

This configuration brings the error, however, adding separate `10.10.1.1/24` address to the `int0` (opposing just `10.10.0.1\16`) solved the issue, like so:

```
# route -n                              
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         <external IP>   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0     U     0      0        0 int0
10.10.1.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0     U     0      0        0 int0
10.24.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
10.150.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
<external IP>   0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Everything works fine now.

Comment: A wild guess - try `listen 10.10.0.1:443 ipv6only=off ssl http2;` and `listen 10.10.1.1:443 ipv6only=off ssl http2;`

Comment: @Alex, is `0.1` and `1.1` IP addresses belongs to same server? Could you provide us your `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: Nope... `bind` param was my wild guess, no luck as well. Btw, this also happens with ipv6 only address.port conf. @IvanShatsky

Comment: @user973254 yes, these all local IP's on the same server.

Comment: @user973254 
```
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.1.1 serv serv
127.0.0.1 localhost

#Custom
10.10.0.1 main.site
10.10.1.1 test.site
```

Comment: @Alex, might be a resolving issue, but anyway try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46005083/973254

Comment: @Alex, also please provide the result of `ip addr sh` by root user

Comment: @user973254 `ip addr sh` added to post. Upstream confing doesn't seem to make any difference - will dig into this a little more anyway.

Comment: @Alex, I don't see `10.10.1.1`, please add output of `route -n`

Comment: @user973254 yup, just updated post. Looks like there was the probem, however it's nature is not very clear to me as `10.10.0.0/16` wouldn't work, but two different assignments with `'10.10.0.0/24` and `10.10.1.0/24` works fine.

Comment: @Alex, yep, I knew it. Good luck.